# How to add @xml:base to my .xml files?

Tags: xml, xslt, docbook

I need a stylesheet to convert my docbook xml files so that they now include a xml:base element to my section tags.  How do I go about doing that (since xml:base needs system and node info???)

Input:

```
<section xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xml:id="voidVisit" version="5">
<title>Void</title>

 <section>
  <title>Screenshot</title>
      <mediaobject>
          <imageobject>
              <imagedata fileref="screenshots/Dialog.png" />
          </imageobject>
      </mediaobject>
 </section>
</section>
```

Output:

```
      ...
      <section xml:id="void" version="5"
           xml:base="file:/C:/Projects/my/proj/trunk/spec/module/components/void.xml">
     <title>Void</title>
     <section>
        <title>Screenshot</title>
        <mediaobject>
           <imageobject>
              <imagedata fileref="screenshots/Dialog.png"/>
           </imageobject>
        </mediaobject>
     </section>
     ...
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In XSLT 2.0 (XPath 2.0) the functions [`static-base-uri()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-static-base-uri) and [`base-uri()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-base-uri) can be used for this purpose**.

Here is a working example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
     <doc xml:base="{base-uri()}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied, the wanted result is produced**:

```
<doc xml:base="file:/C:/CVS-DDN/fxsl-xslt2/data/marrowtr.xml"/>
```

**So, the complete transformation in your case is**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:d="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/d:section">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:attribute name="xml:base" select="base-uri(/)"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**In XSLT 1.0 the solution is** to pass the base-uri as an external parameter (global `xsl:param>`) to the transformation.

Comment: how would I add it to the section rather than wiping out my document?

Comment: @Ace: Read and learn about the *identity transformation*. Here is a good link: http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html . Also search the xslt tag -- there are numerous examples how to use the identity transform to copy everything as-is and only add an attribute to a single element.

Comment: @Ace: I added the code for your case, but, please, do learn the basics.

Comment: Hm, didn't know about the base-uri() function. Good to know. +1